# I cant fix the schedule in telegram bot

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, telegram-bot

I cant set the right timezone in my telegram bot. I developed a Telegram bot that works with the Argentine timezone on my computer but switches to the American timezone on my server; how can I set it to consistently use the Argentine timezone?

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import schedule
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

bot = telebot.TeleBot('mytocken')

user_responses = {}
user_data = {}

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    user_name = message.from_user.first_name

    user_data[user_id] = {'chat_id': user_id, 'user_name': user_name}
    print("Received /start from user:", user_id, "User data:", user_data)

    bot.send_message(user_id, 'hi ')

def schedule_checker():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    user_id = callback.from_user.id
    chat_id = callback.message.chat.id
    user_name = callback.from_user.first_name

    if user_id not in user_data:
        user_data[user_id] = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'user_name': user_name}
        print("New user data added:", user_data)

    if callback.data == 'yes':
        user_responses[user_id] = 'окей! спасибо, что предупредил!'
        bot.send_message('my_id', 'купи сендвичи')
    elif callback.data == 'no':
        user_responses[user_id] = 'окей, спасибо, что предупредил.'
        bot.send_message('my_id', 'не покупай сендвичи')

    if user_id in user_responses:
        bot.edit_message_text(user_responses[user_id], chat_id, callback.message.message_id)

def function_to_run():
    specific_users = [specificuser_id, my_id]  # Список chat_id конкретных пользователей

    for user_id in specific_users:
        if user_id in user_data:  # Проверяем, есть ли пользователь в user_data
            chat_id = user_data[user_id]['chat_id']
            user_name = user_data[user_id]['user_name']
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('да', callback_data='yes')
            btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('нет', callback_data='no')
            markup.add(btn1, btn2)

            try:
                bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Привет, {user_name}! Придёт ли сегодня Кевин?', reply_markup=markup)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error sending message to {chat_id}: {e}")  # Логирование ошибки
        else:
            print(f"User {user_id} not found in user_data")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    schedule.every().tuesday.at("08:00").do(function_to_run)
    schedule.every().thursday.at("08:00").do(function_to_run)
    schedule.every().friday.at("08:00").do(function_to_run)
    Thread(target=schedule_checker).start()
    bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Hello there! I've developed a Telegram bot that sends messages to the user at specific times. It functions correctly on my computer because it's set to the Argentine timezone, which I need. However, when I run this bot on my American server, it operates according to the American timezone. I'm struggling to find a solution to this problem. How can I configure the bot to use the correct timezone? Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: To ensure that your Telegram bot uses the Argentine timezone consistently, regardless of the server's location, you can set the timezone explicitly in your Python script. This can be done by setting the environment variable for the timezone or by using timezone-aware datetime objects in your code.